# Adding new item at 0 position in firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

```
mFirestore.collection("notifications").orderBy("timestamp",Query.Direction.DESCENDING).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>(){
@Override
public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots,@javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e){
        if(e!=null){
        Log.d(TAG,"Error : "+e.getMessage());
        }

        assert documentSnapshots!=null;

        for(DocumentChange doc:documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){

        if(doc.getType()==DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
        String doc_id=doc.getDocument().getId();
        NotificationModel Notifications=doc.getDocument().toObject(NotificationModel.class).withDocId(doc_id);
        allNotifications.add(Notifications);
        notificationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        }
        }
        });
```

I am trying to do that when in firestore collection a new document is added it will add at 0 position. but instead of 0 position a new item is adding at the last position.

Answer (score 0):

Documents in a firestore collection are not stored as an array, but more in a map fashion way, meaning that you can't insert a document at a specific position

You can take a look here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code

```
allNotifications.add(Notifications);
```

to

```
allNotifications.add(0, Notifications);
```

According to the official documentation regarding ArrayList's [add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)) method:

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.

Answer (score 0):

I solve My Query by changing this `allNotifications.add(Notifications);`

to this `allNotifications.add(doc.getNewIndex(),Notifications);`